# Error while creating new web application in SP Server 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration, web-application

I am facing a strange issue while creating a new web application in SharePoint 2013. While creating a new web application it throws below error in Central Admin 2013:

> This content database requires upgrade and could not be attached in
>   this operation. Use either the [stsadm -o addcontentdb] command or
>   [Mount-SPContentDatabase] cmdlet instead.

Please note I am not migrating any content database. I created a new SharePoint Server 2013 farm and tried to create a new web application and ended up having above error.

On reviewing ULS logs, I found some more exceptions:

> An error occured while trying to grant the user domain1\sp_admin
>   access to the WSS_Content_SP4444 database on the SQL server,
>   ow-db-srv.  This may be expected if the caller does not have
>   permission to perform this operation in sql server or if the database
>   is read-only.  To ensure that SharePoint functions correctly, manually
>   grant this user access to the database before performing this
>   operation.  The user must also be granted access to the SPDataAccess
>   group in the database.  The following information was provided with
>   this error: Cannot alter the role 'SPDataAccess', because it does not
>   exist or you do not have permission.
>
> SqlError: 'Cannot alter the role 'SPDataAccess', because it does not
>   exist or you do not have permission.'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data
>   Provider' Number: 15151 State: 1 Class: 16 Procedure: '' LineNumber: 1
>   Server: 'ow-db-srv'
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot alter the role
>   'SPDataAccess', because it does not exist or you do not have
>   permission.

I checked in SQL Server and found the admin has sufficient permissions to create new web applications because this is the same account through which I installed SharePoint 2013.

Any inputs to above issue are welcome.

Comment: does the app pool account have necessary privileges ?  Check this link - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863.aspx

Comment: Are you creating the DB using UI or PowerShell? Maybe you are missing Shell permission. If you are using PS try Add-SPShellAdmin cmd let. If all permission are ok there might be an issue with your sec tokens check the time sync with  your domain controllers. (run this command from CA server the W32tm /monitor /domain:domain1). If the sync isn't correct you can get mixed messages (username and password incorrect etc)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds an awful lot like your Farm Administrator account doesn't have the 'Security Admin' role.  The account you want to double check is the one running the Timer Job and the Central Administration application pool.  That's the mitochondria of SharePoint.